# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getCategoryIds() on boolean in

Tags: magento-1.9

This error is been showing when i am just trying to add product with additional custom option to the product .

Comment: Can you please post the whole error and try explaining a bit more thoroughly what you are trying to do? Adding a product to a product does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are **trying to get category ids** for a product:

Below is the correct way to do this.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
        /*Your logic here*/
  }
```

Try to make this change & your error should be resolved.